# Vue router appends url to current url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, path, vue-router

I am using vue 2. I have registered routes.  Two routes are `memberships` and `memberships/:id`.

When I use:

```js
this.$router.push({ path: 'memberships'} );
```

after this any `this.$router.push` results in appending to

```html
http://localhost:8000/memberships/bronze
http://localhost:8000/memberships/silver
```

and `http://localhost:8000/memberships/shop` in place of `http://localhost:8000/shop`

and `http://localhost:8000/memberships/deals` in place of `http://localhost:8000/deals`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a leading slash in all of your base route paths:

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/memberships' });
```

Do this in the base route definitions too.  Also you can name your routes and push by name:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'memberships'} );
```